# How to insert client-rendered HTML into DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've just rendered some HTML in the browser using a library like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), or [dust](http://www.dustjs.com/). For example, `"<div><p>I'm text!</p></div>"`.

If I was using a framework like React or Ember, the rendered template would automatically be inserted into the DOM (in the least invasive way due to virtual DOM diffing). But these libraries just give me a string of HTML. How do I use that?

Is it as simple as finding the desired parent DOM node and setting `innerHTML`? Is there a DOM diffing library not tied into React that I can use?

[edit] If I rerender the text, and it's the same, inserting into the DOM should ideally be idempotent, and not even disturb event event handlers.

Comment: You want a way to add HTML to DOM natively but without using messy strings? `.createElement(TAG)`

Comment: No, I have the string of several nested elements already, and want to add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

> *...I have the string of several nested elements already, and want to add it to the DOM.*

You can use `.innerHTML` property, but it has [problems](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/12/38/). A better alternative is a method that's like `.innerHTML` called [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). It doesn't have the [problems](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/12/38/) that `innerHTML` has, it's faster, and you have options that allow you to place your string *before/after/prepend/append on/in* an element.

> #### Signature
>
> ```
> element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
> ```
>
> **position** determines where the **text** goes relative to the **element**. It must be one of the following values:
>
> ```
> *beforebegin*// <== insert before the element
>   <element>
>       *afterbegin*// <== insert before the element's content (prepend)
>       <child>Content</child>
>       <child>Content</child>
>       <child>Content</child>
>       <child>Content</child>
>       Content
>       *beforeend*// <== insert after the element's content (append)
>   </element>
>   *afterend* // <== insert after the element
> ```

### Snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  font: 400 12px/1.2 Consolas;
}

main {
  height: auto;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px dashed red;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

section {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dotted white;
  background: rgba(181, 111, 0, .6);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: rgba(255, 30, 30, .3);
}

fieldset {
  display: table-row;
  width: 90%;
}

.bb {
  height: 30px;
  color: gold;
  border-color: gold;
}

.ab {
  height: 30px;
  color: lightgreen;
  border-color: lightgreen;
}

.be {
  height: 30px;
  color: #0022ef;
  border-color: #0022ef;
}

.ae {
  height: 30px;
  color: violet;
  border-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <fieldset>
      <button onclick='bb()'>main beforebegin</button>
      <button onclick='ab()'>main afterbegin</button>
      <button onclick='be()'>main beforeend</button>
      <button onclick='ae()'>main afterend</button>
    </fieldset>
  </header>
  <main id='core' class='topic'>
    <article class='category'>
      <section id='I'>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </section>
      <section id='1I'>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article class='category'>
      <section id='III'>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer class='footer'>

  </footer>
  <script>
    function bb() {
      document.querySelector('main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="bb">This div has been inserted at position beforebegin</div>');
    }

    function ab() {
      document.querySelector('.topic').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="ab">This div has been inserted at position afterbegin</div>');
    }

    function be() {
      document.querySelector('#core').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="be">This div has been inserted at position beforeend</div>');
    }

    function ae() {
      document.querySelector('main#core.topic').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="ae">This div has been inserted at position afterend</div>');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very cool! But this will insert a new copy of the rendered template on each run.

Comment: @mgold So you just need to use it once as if when editing your source? Or did you need something that's dynamic? Or did you want something interactive and dynamic? There is a [HTML <template> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). There is also ["tagged template literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals) from ES6.